# How to duplicate rows while using mutate in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm currently trying to add multiple columns to my dataframe using mutate.

This is what I started with:

```
new_df <- old_df %>% 
  mutate(demo = c("audience 1", "audience 2")
```

Here's what I wanted to happen

```
game demo
1    audience 1
1    audience 2
2    audience 1
2    audience 2
```

However this just results in an error. I know this is just my bad beginner syntax, can someone help?

Comment: Do you have to use `mutate`? You could do something like `old_df$demo <- 
rep(c("audience 1", "audience 2"), times = nrow(old_df)/2)` or something similar

Comment: Can you show us `old_df` before your `mutate()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your `old_df` has just rows, and you'd like to add both values of `demo` for each value of `game`. If I've got that right, you can use [tidyr::expand_grid()](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/expand_grid.html):

```r
library(tidyr)

old_df <- data.frame(game = 1:2)

old_df %>% 
  expand_grid(demo = c("audience 1", "audience 2"))

#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>    game demo      
#>   <int> <chr>     
#> 1     1 audience 1
#> 2     1 audience 2
#> 3     2 audience 1
#> 4     2 audience 2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the function I needed :) I learned something new today!

Comment: You're welcome! [tidyr::expand()](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/expand.html) and [complete()](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html) are similar functions that also come in handy for generating combinations of values.

Answer (score 2):

The answers here are good ones, but I'll put the following solution here because it is simple, and when working with data I've often been surprised how useful a careful application of `merge()` from base R can be.

```
old_df <- data.frame(game = 1:2)
demo_df <- data.frame(demo = c("audience 1", "audience 2"))

merge(demo_df, old_df)
        demo game
1 audience 1    1
2 audience 2    1
3 audience 1    2
4 audience 2    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with a reprex:

```
library(dplyr)

data("mtcars")

old_df = mtcars

new_df <- old_df %>% 
  mutate(demo = c("audience 1", "audience 2")
```

This fails, because you are missing a parenthesis to close the mutate call:

```
Error: Incomplete expression: 
new_df <- old_df %>% 
  mutate(demo = c("audience 1", "audience 2")
```

Fixing this is insufficient though, as mutate is expecting a vector of the same length (no. of rows) as the table:

```
new_df <- old_df %>% 
  mutate(demo = c("audience 1", "audience 2"))

Error in mutate(., demo = c("audience 1", "audience 2")) : 
✖ `demo` must be size 32 or 1, not 2.
```

I am guessing you want it to cycle through audience 1 and 2 for all rows. Just be careful that the total number of rows is even and not odd:

```
pattern = c("audience 1", "audience 2")

new_df <- old_df %>% 
  mutate(demo = rep(pattern, length.out = nrow(old_df)))


new_df %>%
    select(1:3, demo)
```

In essence, this repeats the pattern to fill the length of `length.out`. Hope this helps!